# ListBox does not refresh ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I´ve already done some research on that problem, but I can´t find a workaround.

Here´s the problem:

I have an observableCollection of my custom class ListedNote. At first the ListBox displays the data, but there are some datas which are loaded async and won´t be updated. (e.g. a user picture)

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="Content" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxCardFBLikeTemplate}"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

The ViewModel

```
....
private ObservableCollection<ListedNote> notes;

public ObservableCollection<ListedNote> Notes
        {
            get { return notes; }
            set { notes = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Notes); }
        }
private void LoadAttachmentsAsync(ListedNote note)
        {
            Async.Call(() => this.ServiceConnector.RetrieveAnnouncementAttachment(note.IdValue),
                mm =>
                {
                    if (mm != null)
                    {
                        if (mm.MultimediaType.IsPicture)
                            note.AttachedPicture = mm;
                        else
                            note.AttachedFile = mm;

                        note.AttachmentData = new List<byte>(mm.Data);

                        var index = this.Notes.IndexOf(note);
                        if (index >= 0)
                            this.Notes[index] = note;


                    }
                });
        }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` will only notify the UI when the collection's contents have changed: that is, when a `ListedNote` is added or removed.  It won't notify the UI if the properties of a `ListedNote` already in the collection change.

Your `ListedNote` class needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, in order for the UI to know that a property has changed on an individial note.

Comment: Does ObservableCollection not notify overritings as done in my viewModel?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` will *only* notify when the contents of your collection are changed - that is, when you *add or remove* an item.  Changing a property of an item in your collection *doesn't* change the items that are in your collection, and so `ObservableCollection` won't help you.  You need your `ListedNote` class to notify the UI when *its* properties change.